# lseek cause segmentation file in O_APPEND mod

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, append

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    int fd;
    off_t foffset;
    char* fpath;
    char* rbuf;
    if(argc!=2){
        printf("insert filename as argument!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(fpath,argv[1]);
    if( (fd = open(fpath,O_RDWR | O_APPEND)) <0 )
        perror("error on open()");
    //try to use lseek in file opened in O_APPEND mode
    char buf[] = "I'm appending some text!\n"; 
    if( write(fd, buf , sizeof(buf)) <0 )
        perror("error on write()");
    printf("the write() operation was succesful, let's try to seek and read the file..\n");
    foffset = lseek(fd,0L,SEEK_CUR);
    if(foffset<0)
        perror("error on lseek() :");
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it generate a segmentation fault when I execute this code??
The segFault occurs only if the lseek operation is added, otherwise is fine.

Comment: `fpath` is a wild pointer

Answer (score 2):

`fpath` is a wild pointer, i.e. you haven't allocated any storage for it before you call `strcpy`. However since you only need a `const char *` for the file name you can just make the following change.

Change:

```
strcpy(fpath,argv[1]);
```

to:

```
fpath = argv[1];
```

Comment: Genius!! Why the heck did that happen?? How does strcpy create the issue?

Comment: but why can't I read from the file with read()?? it always returns 0!

Comment: @ichigo663 undefined behaviour created the issue, not strcpy. It just so happens that your call to strcpy was the undefined behaviour. Which book are you reading? `lseek(fd,0L,SEEK_CUR);` looks wrong. Perhaps you wish to rewind the file, in which case you should be using `lseek(fd,0L,SEEK_SET);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `fpath` separately, change your definition:

```
char fpath[30];
```

Now your `strcpy` will work as expected (though you should check the length of the string is under 30). You can just pass `argv[1]` directly, however, to `open`, since you're not doing anything else with it.